# Print the result of string after a particular key word

Tags: linux, awk, grep, find, printf

Below output is an  one liner output, where ma-name & emailID are common values. I would need to print the next values of ma-name & emailID parallel one after the other. please suggest a way to do it

sample text file

```
{"ma":{"ma-name":"svc"},"team-dl":{"emailID":"opt"},"disable":{"disable":false}},{"ma":{"ma-name":"ns"},"team-dl":{"emailID":"Solutions"},"disable":{"disable":false}},{"ma":{"ma-name":"mea"},"team-dl":{"emailID":"DISTA"},"disable":{"disable":false}}
```

Expected output

```
svc opt
ns Solutions
mea DISTA
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sed` to turn the input into valid `JSON` so we can run `jq` on it:

```
$ sed 's/.*/[&]/' file |
    jq -r '.[] | (."ma"."ma-name" + " " + ."team-dl"."emailID")'
svc opt
ns Solutions
mea DISTA
```

Comment: I normally wouldn't post an answer without the OP providing their own attempt in the question but I was just so happy to actually figure out a `jq` solution for once :-).